# What's the correct way to set the text of a UILabel that's part of an IBOutletCollection

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel, iboutletcollection

I have a series of UILabels that form part of an IBOutletCollection

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *labelCollection;
```

I have sequentially set the tags of the UILabels to 0,1,2,3 ... and I have sorted the *labelCollection  by tag number.  Thus, object '0' in the IBOutletCollection array is the UILabel with tag '0' etc.

Using the following function I can update the text of the UILabel at a particular obj/tag:

```
- (void) updateLabelAtTag:(int)objId {
        [[self.labelCollection objectAtIndex:objId] setText:@"my new text"]; 
    }

}
```

This works fine, however, when you click on the setText: in the IDE, Xcode Quick Help complains

```
setText:
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *text
iOS (2.0 and later) 
Deprecated: Use the textLabel and detailTextLabel properties instead.
The text of the cell.
UITableViewCell.h
```

For the life of me I can't figure out what UITableViewCell has to do with this situation.  I certainly don't appear to be able to access the textLabel or detailTextLabel properties.

Question:  Am I using a deprecated property, or has Xcode got it wrong in this instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode.  I suspect

```
 [(UILabel *)[self.labelCollection objectAtIndex:objId] setText:@"my new text"];
```

would make it go away.

Comment: Yes!  You are correct.  I should have thought to cast it.  +1 for more coffee.